# Weird IPv4 Representation with Leading zero(s)?

Tags: network-programming, ip, ipv4

Writing a small validator and parser of string representations of IPv4, I wonder if there are IP-Representations like 127.000.000.001 out there? I know this is strange but appears to be legal IP-Representations after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can happen [here's an example](http://answers.splunk.com/answers/139806/weird-ip-address-with-leading-zeros.html).

Problem is, leading zeroes in an IP can sometimes [mean that the IP is written in octal](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/115388).